# bootstrap lightbox image and content for single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have 4 images on my page , each image consist of a header title and content which i call using advanced custom fields. If clicked on any one of these images i would like a lightbox with image, header and content to appear for which ever one i clicked on.

So far i have managed to get it working for only the first image.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle-modal").click(function(){
    $("#lightBoxId").modal('toggle');
});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li class="list-item-1">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#lightBoxId">
     <?php if (isset($images['url']) && !empty($images['url'])) : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $images['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images['alt']; ?>" />
         <p class="name-field"><?php echo $images['description']; ?></p>
         <p class="text-field"><?php echo $images['caption']; ?></p>
     <?php endif; ?>
    </a>

    <div id="lightBoxId" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <img src="<?php echo $images['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images['alt']; ?>" />
                    <p class="name-field"><?php echo $images['description']; ?></p>
                    <p class="text-field"><?php echo $images['caption']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

Now i have another 3 li's i want to display individually within their own lightboxes. how would i go about achieving this?

**Example of second < li > :**

```
<li>
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="#lightBoxId">
     <?php if (isset($images2['url']) && !empty($images2['url'])) : ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $images2['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images2['alt']; ?>" />
       <p class="name-field"><?php echo $images2['description']; ?></p>
       <p class="text-field"><?php echo $images2['caption']; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
   <div id="lightBoxId" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <img src="<?php echo $images['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images['alt']; ?>" />
                    <p class="name-field"><?php echo $images['description']; ?></p>
                    <p class="text-field"><?php echo $images['caption']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<li>
```

Currently my script is working only for the first < li > , i want it to work for all the li's i have and i have 4 of them on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind , im using bootstrap default theme, i just gave the second list display div an unique id as suppose to and it worked..

**Example of second < li > : fixed**

```
<li>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#lightBoxId-second">
     <?php if (isset($images2['url']) && !empty($images2['url'])) : ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $images2['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images2['alt']; ?>" />
         <p class="name-field"><?php echo $images2['description']; ?></p>
         <p class="text-field"><?php echo $images2['caption']; ?></p>
     <?php endif; ?>
    </a>

    <div id="lightBoxId-second" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <img src="<?php echo $images2['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images2['alt']; ?>" />
                    <p class="name-field"><?php echo $images2['description']; ?></p>
                    <p class="text-field"><?php echo $images2['caption']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

this displayed my second li in his own lightbox with its unique image and content.